# When using MUIRichTextEditor as a redux form Field cursor keeps returning to start

Tags: redux, material-ui, rich-text-editor, draftjs

When using MUIRichTextEditor as  a redux form field, with every key stroke, redux updates the store and then my component render function is called. I want to set the new value of the MUIRichTextEditor component and I am using the documented prop defaultValue for that. The problem is that it's of type Draft.Model.Encoding.RawDraftContentState and based on my understanding this means I don't have a way to set the cursor position.
It could of helped me if I was able to set a new EditorState object as value to the component but I was unable to find a way to do that. Below is a relevant code snippet:

```
class MYRichText extends Component {
    lastRichTextHTMLValue = null;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    onRichTextChange = (state) => {
    // avoid infinite loop - do not call redux unless the value changed
        const richTextAsHTML = stateToHTML(state.getCurrentContent());
        if (this.lastRichTextHTMLValue || this.lastRichTextHTMLValue !== richTextAsHTML) {
            this.lastRichTextHTMLValue = richTextAsHTML;
            this.props.input.onChange(richTextAsHTML);
        }
    };

    render() {
        const htmlValue = this.props.input.value ? this.props.input.value : "<p><br></p>";
        const convertedValue = convertFromHTML(htmlValue);
        const valueAsContentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
            convertedValue.contentBlocks,
            convertedValue.entityMap
        );
        const defaultValue = JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(valueAsContentState));

        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={richEditorTheme}>
                <MUIRichTextEditor
                    controls={["title", "bold", "italic", "underline", "strikethrough"]}
                    label="Description"
                    defaultValue={defaultValue}
                    onChange={this.onRichTextChange}
                />
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to use the MUIRichTextEditor as uncontrolled component. It means not notifying redux about any change in the editor and then get the editor value from the component upon submit instead of getting it from the redux form field.
If the submit is handled at a HOC where you do not have access to the value of the editor you can use the onChange handler to update the HOC about changes in the value. As follows:

```
         onRichTextChange = (state) => {
             ...
             this.props.updateHOC(newValue); 

          };
```

where updateHOC is a parameter given to your component by the HOC via props